# Azure DevOps doesn't allow me to change the security settings from web console

Tags: azure-devops

I want to change the security settings of my repository project by selecting `More options > Security` in Azure DevOps web console / browser. But when I do so, I get the below error:

> Your administrator has disabled web editing for this repository. You cannot add, delete, rename, or edit files via the web.

I am an administrator myself and not sure what setting I should change and where in Azure DevOps, given that it has varying levels of permissions and that the error message above is more cryptic that I don't see a setting that matches it anywhere.

Note: I am also admin of an external group where access permissions are restricted to many of the projects in this repository. Not sure if this deny is over-riding my permissions and how to go about solving the issue if this is the case.

I really would appreciate your help in fixing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your administrator has disabled web editing for this repository. You cannot add, delete, rename, or edit files via the web.

As far as I know, this issue should appear in the TFVC repo.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to navigate to **Project Settings -> Repositories -> TFVC Repo -> Settings** and enable the **Web editing** option.

[image]